# Read Data From Text Field in TableView Dynamic Cell in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, swift5, custom-cell

I want to read the text in the text fields in my dynamic cells in the table view.

Each cell has two text fields and the user can add more cells.

My question :
How can I read the values from text fields (textField1 & textField2)  and add them to my cards struct?

In the Cards struct there are two variables. frontLabel and backLabel as string

My table View:

```
class AddFCViewController: UIViewController  {

   
    var numberOfTextFields = 1
    var cards = [Cards]()
    
    
    
    // Table View
    let tableView : UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .purple
        
        return tableView
    }()
    
   
    // Add Button
    let addButtton : UIButton = {
       let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.backgroundColor = .link
        btn.setTitle("Ekle", for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()
    
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureTableView()
        configureAddButton()


        
    }
    
    
   
    
    // MARK: - Configure Add Button
    func configureAddButton() {
        view.addSubview(addButtton)
       
        addButtton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Add Button Tapped MEthod
    @objc func addButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
        numberOfTextFields += 1
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
 
    // MARK: - Configure Table View
    func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        setTableViewDelegates()
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 100
        tableView.register(AddFCCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddFCCell")
       
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table View Delegates
    func setTableViewDelegates() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}


// MARK: - Table View Extension & Delegate Methods

extension AddFCViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfTextFields
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddFCCell") as! AddFCCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.textField1.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.textField2.tag = indexPath.row
        print(cell.textField1.tag)
        print(cell.textField2.tag)
        
//        cell.textField1.text = cards[indexPath.row].frontLabel
//        cell.textField2.text = cards[indexPath.row].backLabel
  

        cell.textField1.delegate = self
        

        cell.backgroundColor = .purple

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
//        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
   
  
    
}
```

Here is my custom Cell Class.

```
class AddFCCell: UITableViewCell {
   
    
    // MARK: - Text Field 1
    let textField1 : UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textField.placeholder = "TYPE HERE SOMETHING"
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

        return textField
    }()
    
    
    // MARK: - Text Field 2
    let textField2 : UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textField.placeholder = "TYPE HERE SOMETHING"
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

        return textField
    }()

    // MARK: - view Did Load
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(textField1)
        contentView.addSubview(textField2)
        
        configureTextBox1(textField: textField1)
        configureTextBox2(textField: textField2)
    }
  
    
    // MARK: - Configure Text Box 1 Function
    func configureTextBox1(textField : UITextField) {
        
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 20
     
    }
    
    // MARK: - Configure Text Box 2 Function
    func configureTextBox2(textField : UITextField) {
        
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 20
     
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

PS - I deleted some of my constraints code as it was just too much code there.

Comment: " How can I read the values from text fields" When? When user taps on some specific button or when user stops editing the textfield?

Comment: Sorry for the missing information. When the user finish editing, I want to read the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change couple of things,

**1.** Get rid of `numberOfTextFields`

**2.** Use `var cards = [Cards]()` to return the number of cells in tableView

**3.** Initialize `cards` with a single `Cards` instance and set its property to nil. So I would have Cards implementation as

```
struct Cards {
    var frontLabel: String?
    var backLabel: String?
}
```

**4.** Initialize `cards` array as

```
var cards = [Cards()]
```

**5.** Return number of rows from arrays count

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return cards.count
    }
```

**6.** I would migrate text field delegate responsibilities  to Cell instead of moving it to ViewController and I would have a delegate in `AddFCCell` to update the ViewController about text changes

```
@objc protocol AddFCCellDelegate {
    func updateCard(with frontText: String?, backText: String?, for cell: AddFCCell)
}

class AddFCCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate:AddFCCellDelegate?
    //.... other codes of yours
}

extension AddFCCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.delegate?.updateCard(with: self.textField1.text, backText: self.textField2.text, for: self)
    }
}
```

**7.** Finally, implement/confirm to `AddFCCellDelegate` in viewController and reload TableView bu updating text

```
extension ViewController: AddFCCellDelegate {
    func updateCard(with frontText: String?, backText: String?, for cell: AddFCCell) {
        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        self.cards[indexPath.row].frontLabel = frontText
        self.cards[indexPath.row].backLabel = backText
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

**8.** Update `CellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddFCCell") as! AddFCCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.textField1.text = cards[indexPath.row].frontLabel
        cell.textField2.text = cards[indexPath.row].backLabel


        cell.backgroundColor = .purple

        return cell
    }
```

You can obviously implement a efficient protocol and return/update only specific variable in Cards struct based on which textField was modified n all, but the code posted here is only to give you an idea and to get started with

**EDIT 1:**

Make sure you have set your TextFields delegate right

```
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(textField1)
        textField1.delegate = self
        contentView.addSubview(textField2)
        textField2.delegate = self

        configureTextBox1(textField: textField1)
        configureTextBox2(textField: textField2)
    }
```

Comment: thank you Sandeep. Your answer definitely pushed me forward however I cannot still access to those textField values.

I updated my code with your answer and debug it and Cards object textFields returns nil value.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nBytLl0HkpzVrsBCs_WbdwE8oiCUlO1f/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @evrim-demir: Show your Cell code, also put a breakpoint and check if your text field delegates are triggering on cell (even before that make sure you have set cell as textfields delegate)

Comment: here is my cell code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ykxOluCsGf6SVJz92lgfTt2XtOd7spbF/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJB8zTCdDKLVYyll4SFFxOadu7ow-vSf/view?usp=drivesdk

and I confirm that delegates are being triggered in the cell 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UDM_q1Qa2C5S4cAE5sDy1epKa-E8aJEt/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @evrim-demir: You haven't done anything I mentioned in my answer, and expect the code to work ? 1. You are setting textfields delegate to be ViewController which I have removed check `cellForRowAt` method, I have clearly deleted `cell.textField1.delegate = self` and for textField2 as well 2. You havent set the ViewController to be the delegate of cell `cell.delegate = self` check `cellForRowAt` again 3. You havent set the cell to be textfields delegate check `init` method of `AddFCCell` clearly I have added `textField1.delegate = self` If none of those things are set how will it work?

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep. It's 'almost' working. There are some minor issues I will be tackling. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pLUSrNUTJh8pz74WQKgLSThoqwrlau6s/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @evrim-demir: This happens if there is an inconsistency in data source, like you added a card to array but havent reloaded the tableview yet or if you have deleted one and havent updated the tableView, in such cases tableView will have outdated index path for cell which causes these crashes, you have to be careful to solve those things, obvious and simple solution would be to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` instead of `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` but that wont be efficient, if you have fairly less number of rows and dont have time to analyze the issue useit

Answer (score 0):

You can add placeholder text to both text filed, make sure both place holder text are different, here I am trying to assign uniq identifier to textfield with tag.

&

retrieve text field value by comparing place holder text in textFieldDidBeginEditing.

```
cell.textField1.tag = indexPath.row

cell.textField2.tag = indexPath.row

cell.textField1.placeholder = "1"

cell.textField2.placeholder = "2"



func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

      if(textField.tag && placeholder){
      }

 }
```

It is not a proper solution but by this way you can differentiate both text filed with same tag.